# Is it safe to replace "strings" inside .class file? Or it is better to recompile?

Tags: java, regex, sed, disassembly

The main question is: is it safe to change some 'string" information inside `*.class` file (java compiled classes).

What I'm doing is:

using regexp I'm trying to find all IP address stings inside some compiled project"

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -E "[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.1\.[0-9]{0,3}"
```

This command telling me that some binary files are matching my regexp. And it is pointing that this binary files are `.jar` and `.class`. When I open those `.class` files using `vi` I can see a lot of strange characters and also something like "http://192.168.1.111" among this binary garbage.

My final task is replace all IP addresses (using `sed -i`) to FQDN.

Is it safe? Or only working solution to disassemble all project and recompile again?

---

### Added after answers.

I test it this way:

Create Change.java

```java
public class Change {

    public static String CHANGE_ME="SOME_TEST_STRING";

    public static void main (String[] argv){
        System.out.println(CHANGE_ME);
    }
}
```

Run it and saw this in terminal

```
$ java Change
SOME_TEST_STRING
```

Compile it and run replacing:

`sed -i 's/SOME_TEST_STRING/AAAAA/g' Change.class`

After this run again

```
$ java Change 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file Change
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

Comment: When you recompile, I would switch to using a `properties` file and then you can change that as much as you like without having to recompile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that is not safe. It is so far from safe that it's outside the solar system. Recompile the project.

You could use sed to replace the IP in the source code, though. That has a good chance of working.

Comment: Could you please look at @vbezhenar answer and say your pros and cons

Comment: It may sometimes work for class files (not for jars), if (and only if) the strings have the same length. Even with these restrictions, there are many ways it can go wrong. It is possible that the byte sequence matches code outside of string literals (especially for short strings or those that clash with class names etc). It is possible that javac generates code that assumes a string has a certain value, such as a compiletime substitution of a hash value. Granted, javac does not optimize heavily, but this may be different if a shrinker/optimizer/obfuscator like Proguard is involved.

Comment: This last case is particularly worrying wrt safety because you may end up with bytecode that almost works and misbehaves only sometimes under unspecific circumstances. Imagine having a key in a hash table that has different hash codes in different parts of the program, to run with the previous example, and that one of those parts is rarely used, so that you don't spot the error right away. This is not a situation in which you want to put yourself if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

String in `.class` file is encoded with 2 bytes representing its bytes length, then its byte representation in modified UTF-8 encoding. You can safely replace uniqoue ASCII string with the same length. Other replacements are not safe. And that's not recommended anyway, if you have access to sources, you should recompile files.

Example how that works:

```
$ cat Test.java
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }
}

$ javac Test.java
$ java Test
Hello, World!
$ hexdump -C Test.class
...
00000060  2f 53 74 72 69 6e 67 3b  29 56 01 00 0a 53 6f 75  |/String;)V...Sou|
00000070  72 63 65 46 69 6c 65 01  00 09 54 65 73 74 2e 6a  |rceFile...Test.j|
00000080  61 76 61 0c 00 07 00 08  07 00 17 0c 00 18 00 19  |ava.............|
00000090  01 00 0d 48 65 6c 6c 6f  2c 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21  |...Hello, World!|
000000a0  07 00 1a 0c 00 1b 00 1c  01 00 04 54 65 73 74 01  |...........Test.|
000000b0  00 10 6a 61 76 61 2f 6c  61 6e 67 2f 4f 62 6a 65  |..java/lang/Obje|
000000c0  63 74 01 00 10 6a 61 76  61 2f 6c 61 6e 67 2f 53  |ct...java/lang/S|
...
```

we can see that "Hello, World!" string is located at 0x93 offset. Now we will replace that string with "Hello, Earth!".

```
$ echo -n Hello, Earth! | dd conv=notrunc of=Test.class bs=1 seek=$((0x93))
$ java Test
Hello, Earth!
```

`echo -n Hello Earth!` prints 12 bytes to its stdout. `dd conv=notrunc of=Test.class bs=1 seek=$((0x93))` replaces bytes in the file `Test.class` from 0x93 offset with its input (`Hello Earth` in our case).

here's full transcript: http://pastebin.com/rJi4cRX1

Comment: Very interesting. Could you please clarify what to do? I'm trying to do something like `sed -i 's/SOME_TEST_STRING/01010011 01001111 01001101 01000101 /g' Change.class` but it is also not working

Comment: First of all sed doesn't work with binary files (at least in my system). I pasted explanation here: http://pastebin.com/rJi4cRX1

Comment: thanks for example. If you have time could you please add last dd command to answer and little explanation. And add pastebin link to answer. May be some one else would add pros and cons

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will backup project and try your solution

Answer (score 2):

Is not safe.

If it is our project you should have all variables (like IP, Ports, and stuff...) in a txt outside file.

After, you can change the file and only re-run the java application.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my project :(